# Yesod -- devel.hs: connect: does not exist (Connection refused)

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, haskell-warp

I'm moving a web app to a new server and upgrading the project from Yesod 1.2 to 1.4.  When I ran yesod devel I got the following error:

```
Starting development server...
Starting devel application
Devel application launched: http://localhost:3000
devel.hs: connect: does not exist (Connection refused)
Exit code: ExitFailure 1
```

I'm not sure how to debug this quickly.  This is running on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.  I'm able to run another web server on port 3000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked it down to using Database.Memcache.Server but not having memcached running.  The Yesod upgrade wasn't related.

Comment: and, this is weird. happened to me too. not running mongo !!

Answer (score 0):

Some info that could be useful:

- your setting.yml
- version of warp
- content of /etc/hosts file

Maybe as a quick test you could try another port (e.g. 4000). I think the way to do that is pass the `-p` option to the `yesod devel` command.

```
yesod devel -p 4000
```